# How to compare values in two array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a two arrays of objects

```
  arrNew =  [ { RecordId: '181049', DateCreated: 1563447093133 },
              { RecordId: '187020', DateCreated: 1563447093134 } ]

   arrNew2 = [ { RecordId: '181049', DateCreated: 1563447093134 },
               { RecordId: '187020', DateCreated: 1563447093134 },
               { RecordId: '187021', DateCreated: 1563447093134 } ]
```

what i need to do is to take `RecordID` from first array and `RecordId` from second array and if RecordId matches between arrays do nothing but i there is new record return true.

```
for (let index = 0; index < newArr.length; index++) {
    const element = newArr[index];

    for (let index = 0; index < newArr2.length; index++) {
      const element2 = newArr2[index];
      if(element.RecordId == element2.RecordId){
        console.log('true', '1')
      }else{
        console.log('false', '2')
      }
    }
 }
```

output

```
true 1
false 2
false 2
true 1
```

which is not okey

what how to correct it?

Comment: what means value? please add the wanted result.

Comment: Your console is working correctly, any reason for it to be not okay? Moreover your variables must be renamed

Comment: I want to compare RecordId if it is equal to RecordId in second array. out put i want it true, true it this case

Comment: it's not clear the kind of comparison you want to implements, the two arrays always has the same lenght? Do you want to compare just the first property?

Comment: I think it is comparing each one ith each one i need to search for RecordId in second one and if not consle false

Comment: You need to write your desired result. It's not clear what you wish for.

Comment: ok let me re write it

Comment: please take a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of known `RecordId` and filter the array by checking the set.

The result of filtering is ready for further processing.

The advantage is to have only two loops, one for generating the set and the other for getting unknown elements instead of iterating one array over and over for getting matches.

```js
var array1 = [{ RecordId: '181049', DateCreated: 1563447093133 }, { RecordId: '187020', DateCreated: 1563447093134 }],
    array2 = [{ RecordId: '181049', DateCreated: 1563447093134 }, { RecordId: '187020', DateCreated: 1563447093134 }, { RecordId: '187021', DateCreated: 1563447093134 }],
    known = new Set(array1.map(({ RecordId }) => RecordId)),
    unknown = array2.filter(({ RecordId }) => !known.has(RecordId));

console.log(unknown);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses same `index` variable for different loops. But your naive implementation looks okay so far. Just quick fix it by using another variable `index2` for nested loop:

```js
  newArr =  [ { RecordId: '181049', DateCreated: 1563447093133 },
              { RecordId: '187020', DateCreated: 1563447093134 } ]

   newArr2 = [ { RecordId: '181049', DateCreated: 1563447093134 },
               { RecordId: '187020', DateCreated: 1563447093134 } ]

for (let index = 0; index < newArr.length; index++) {
    const element = newArr[index];

    for (let index2 = 0; index2 < newArr2.length; index2++) {
      const element2 = newArr2[index2];
      if(element.RecordId == element2.RecordId){
        console.log('true', '1')
      }else{
        console.log('false', '2')
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you arrays are not equal (since you did not say they are always equal) so we can use the length of the shorter array (Trying to compare a[3] with b[3] if B only has 3 objects in it you will get an error).

```
var max = 0; //so we now the max index we can go to

if(arrNew.length > arrNew2.length){
  max = arrNew2.length;
}else{
  max = arrNew.length;
}

for(var i=0;i<max;i++){
  if(arrNew[i].RecordId == arrNew2[i].RecordId)
  {
    console.log(true);
  }else{
    console.log(false);
  }
}
```